# Use run() instead of main

Tags: java, runnable

In my program I want to use Runnable's `public void run ()` as Main function to start my program. So I extended from it but can't get it to work.
I know about Threads but I don't understand how to use them in this case.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you considered the idea of launching your thread from the `main` method? It's not any different from starting a thread from any other method.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your statement *"I extended from it"*, I assume you meant `Runnable`. In that case, then you just need to wrap your `Runnable` in a `Thread` and `start` it.

All Java programs have to start from a main method.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    new Thread(new YourRunnable()).start(); // starts a new thread

    // All code below here will run in the current thread
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`run()` is the method invoked when a new thread is started. `main()` is the entry point of a Java program. You should either call `run()` from `main()` or start a new thread from `main()` with your runnable.

Answer (score 0):

Every java program will start with it's main method. There is no way around this.

Of course what you could do is create a Thread (or a Runnable) and start it (run it).